# How do I recover from a lost git branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, recovery

I have a project I am working on which I started on a local repo. I recently had someone create a github repo and I uploaded the local repo to github (there were various errors and suggestions, but it eventually looked like it was up there.) After doing that, and pulling from origin/master, I noticed I was missing a month or so of work. Apparently my process wiped out a branch named "echo."

I now want to recover these changes from the lost branch. Here is the current picture:

```
git status
  On branch master
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
  nothing to commit, working directory clean

git branch
  * master

git checkout echo
  error: pathspec 'echo' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

and:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %s"
  5825339 - David Rogers, Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/...
  3c41742 - Someone Else, Initial commit
  6db6654 - unknown, Labels V 1.1.8
  2085c27 - David Rogers, Remove site 29 XML subdirectory from installer
  956c939 - David Rogers, Update user settings on upgrade
  1c39bbc - David Rogers, Update user settings on upgrade
  ac48392 - David Rogers, Initial commit
```

Thanks to the wonderful pages here: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html ,
I can see the bigger picture:

```
git reflog
  5825339 HEAD@{0}: pull origin master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
  6db6654 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from echo to master
  b7642f4 HEAD@{2}: pull origin master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
  bb4cbe2 HEAD@{3}: commit: before github
  9288903 HEAD@{4}: commit: before github
  2e8336a HEAD@{5}: commit: prior to github
  6db6654 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to echo
  6db6654 HEAD@{7}: commit: Labels V 1.1.8
  2085c27 HEAD@{8}: commit: Remove site 29 XML subdirectory from installer
  956c939 HEAD@{9}: commit: Update user settings on upgrade
  1c39bbc HEAD@{10}: commit: Update user settings on upgrade
  ac48392 HEAD@{11}: commit (initial): Initial commit
```

(Note the "checkout: moving from master to echo.") Anyways, it looks to me like the head of my missing branch is bb4cbe2. The question is, how to I restore the work and git it up to the origin/master?

Also,

```
git fsck --lost-found
  Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
  dangling commit b7642f4fa87f52b0991f88ce08e29d5aaa43edd3
```

Do I start with : `git reset --hard bb4cbe2`

If I do that, I get:

```
git reset --hard bb4cbe2
  HEAD is now at bb4cbe2 before github

git status
  On branch master
  Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
  and have 3 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
    (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
  Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        xxx.vshost.exe.manifest
        xxx/bin/Release/
        xxx/obj/Release/
        xxx/Release/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Looks like the files are good. Now what? Do I pull from origin? Then push to origin?

I should mention that I have a full disk backup from before the `git reset`.

David

Comment: Your problem is confusing. Your branch is just out of date, right? The issue isn't that dangling commit?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to provide all of the information that may be relevant - in my ignorance I am likely not providing the right stuff.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you deleted your local branch `echo`, but you must have done so, because the `moving from ... to ...` prove that it did exist at one time.  It also seems likely that you've correctly identified `bb4cbe2` as the place `echo` previously pointed, in which case you can just do `git branch echo bb4cbe2` to re-create it as long as the commit ID remains valid (the reflog is keeping it valid, though these are only good for about 30 days if not reachable from the reference's current ID).

Comment: I suspect that since origin on github did not have the echo branch, it was wiped out when I did the pull from origin. It was a week or so ago, so I am unclear on the exact sequence of operations. I am clear, however, that I did not delete anything. :-)

"git branch echo bb4ce2" sounds like a big win... giving it a try then merging into master...

Comment: torek, can you make this an answer? This is the one that a git newbie could understand and feel comfortable doing. It was an incredibly simple solution to the problem. The full sequence was:

 `git branch echo bb4cbe2`,   `git pull`,  `git merge echo`, `git pull`, `git push`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a rebase onto origin/master, then a push to origin/master.  You could also do a merge onto master if you don't care about losing your commit history.

Comment: Are you saying I should start with the `git reset --hard bb4cbe2`?

And then what? `git rebase ...`

Comment: I think based on what you're saying you could do:
git branch echo 
git checkout echo
git rebase master echo
[suggest reading](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: No, branch "echo" does not exist. It disappeared.

Comment: If you reset properly in the reflog it should have brought it back.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a "dangling commit" reported by `git fsck`. I didn't do anything with reflog - just used it as a report.

Comment: Ahhh... yeah I'd reset like you're saying to before it went wrong.  That should bring your branch back.

Comment: It didn't - branch "echo" is gone!

Comment: The last idea I have without access to your repo is to checkout to the dangling commit and see if it is echo.  I've lost branches 100 times and doing a reflog reset has always brought them back for me.  Somtimes it takes a couple tries to find the right sha to reset too though...  Good luck.  I'm pretty sure you'll get it back eventually.  =)

Answer (score 0):

If you see the desired state that you had before within the reflog that you posted, you can just checkout that state from the reflog, eg:

```
git checkout HEAD@{3}
```

And that will bring you to a branch with that state as identified by the reflog. If that was before your pull that's likely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout b7642f4fa87f52b0991f88ce08e29d5aaa43edd3
```

This will check out the dangling commit. If it's what you want to get back, then just create a new branch from that commit and you're golden. If it's not, then you may want to explain your problem a little better.